# Parse a document and returning uniqueness and total number occurrences

Tags: ruby, parsing

I am parsing a document and returning
(1) uniqueness, and
(2) total number occurrence.

I believe my code can still be subjected to review. I would like a review of my code as I have even made it too tightly coupled, and some Dependency Injection would be a nice to have.

How can I make this code better?

### links.log (input file)

```
/help_page/1 126.318.035.038
/help_page/1 126.318.035.038
/contact 184.123.665.067
/home 184.123.665.067
/home/2 444.701.448.104
/help_page/1 929.398.951.889
/index 444.701.448.104
/help_page/1 722.247.931.582
```

### log_processor.rb

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
# frozen_string_literal: true

class LogProcessor
  def initialize(file_name)
    self.log_file = File.read(file_name)
    self.log_stats = {}
    process_log
  end

  def process_log
    log_file.each_line do |line|
      path, ip = line.split(' ')
      log_stats.key?(path) ? log_stats[path] << ip : log_stats[path] = [ip]
    end
  end

  def page_views
    page_views = log_stats.inject({}) { |hash, (path, ips)| hash.merge(path => ips.count) }
    page_views.sort_by { |_path, count| count }.reverse
  end

  def unique_page_views
    unique_page_views = log_stats.inject({}) { |hash, (path, ips)| hash.merge(path => ips.uniq.count) }
    unique_page_views.sort_by { |_path, count| count }.reverse
  end

  private

  attr_accessor :log_file, :log_stats
end

class FileReadError < StandardError
end
```

### log_aggregator.rb

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
# frozen_string_literal: true

require './log_processor'

class LogAggregator
  def initialize(file_path)
    self.log_aggregator = LogProcessor.new(file_path)
  end

  def most_page_views
    page_views = log_aggregator.page_views
    page_views.map { |path, ip_count| "#{path} - #{ip_count} visits" }.join("\n")
  end

  def most_unique_page_views
    unique_views = log_aggregator.unique_page_views
    unique_views.map { |path, uniq_ips| "#{path} - #{uniq_ips} unique views" }.join("\n")
  end

  def aggregator
    ['MOST PAGE VIEWS:', most_page_views,
     'MOST UNIQUE PAGE VIEWS:', most_unique_page_views].join("\n")
  end

  def print_aggregate
    puts aggregator
  end

  private

  attr_accessor :log_aggregator
end
```

### parser.rb

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
# frozen_string_literal: true

require './log_aggregator'

class Parser
  def initialize(file_name)
    @file_name = file_name
  end

  def call
    return expected_command_hint unless file_name_correct?

    parser_result
  end

  private

  attr_reader :file_name

  def parser_result
    LogAggregator.new(file_name).print_aggregate
  end

  def file_name_correct?
    file_name == 'webserver.log'
  end

  def expected_command_hint
    puts 'The right usage is: ./parser.rb webserver.log'
  end
end

Parser.new(ARGV.first).call
```

### running the code:

```bash
ruby ./parser.rb links.log
```

Comment: I [changed the title](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/277320/revisions) so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._". Feel free to [edit] and give it a different title if there is something more appropriate.

Comment: "some Dependency Injection would be a nice to have."  =>  `LogProcessor.new(file_path)`  <=  that is dependency injection.  Block parameters is also dependency injection. Passing arguments to methods is dependency injection.

Comment: Can you show me? I tried Dependency Injection but it's not behaving as expected.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I make this code better?

By making it simpler and shorter.  The current solution creates many unnecessary abstractions.

Idiomatic ruby should embrace the built-in methods of `Hash` and `Array`.  They are very often enough to solve your problems, especially data transformation problem like this one.

So, assume you have read the lines of the file into an variable `lines` which now holds an array of arrays by doing something like:

```
lines = File.read("myfile").split("\n").map { |x| x.split(' ') }
```

You simply want the pages sorted by count, and by unique count.  This is essentially a couple 1-liners:

```
views = lines.reduce({}) { |m, (k, v)| m.merge(k => (m[k] || []) + [v]) }.to_a
view_cnts = views.map { |k, v| [k, v.count] }.sort_by { |x| -x[1] }
uniq_view_cnts = views.map { |k, v| [k, v.uniq.count] }.sort_by { |x| -x[1] }
```

If the code is a bit too dense for you, you can use multi-line `do... end` for the blocks and names such as `page` / `ip` instead of `k` / `v`:

```
view_cnts = views.map do |page, ips|
  [page, ips.count] 
end.sort_by { |(page, cnt)| -cnt }
```

That's a matter of taste and comfort with ruby.  And if you want a hash as output, just call `to_h` at the end.

But creating class abstractions to solve a straightforward data transformation problem is classic over-engineering.

Answer (score 1):

At least one place I can see room for improvement.

> ```
>  def process_log
>    log_file.each_line do |line|
>      path, ip = line.split(' ')
>      log_stats.key?(path) ? log_stats[path] << ip : log_stats[path] = [ip]
>    end
>  end
> ```

Rather, let's default `log_stats[path]` to an empty list if it doesn't yet exist, using `||=`. Then we know we can push `ip` onto that list.

```
  def process_log
    log_file.each_line do |line|
      path, ip = line.split(' ')
      log_stats[path] ||= []
      log_stats[path] << ip 
    end
  end
```

But as `process_log` is never called anywhere else, it's reasonable to use `each_with_object` to generate the hash for `log_stats`.

```
  def initialize(file_name)
    @log_file = File.read(file_name)
    @log_stats = @log_file.lines.each_with_object({}) do |line, h|
      path, ip = line.split(' ', 2)
      h[path] ||= []
      h[path] << ip
    end
  end
```

It's questionable what benefit there is to having private `attr_accessor` methods for `LogProcessor`, unless you just really don't like typing `@` symbols.